# MAT 2005 Oxfords Admissions Exam Question 5 Geometry Solution Verification

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

As ongoing trend, I have been solving old MAT past papers that do not have published solutions. I was wondering if anybody can verify my solution to the following question. [image]

**My solution:**

**(a)** For part a consider the following labaling:

[image]

We get the following simultanius equations

\begin{align}
2x + a + c &=180 \\
a + c + d &= 180 \\
2y+ f &=180 \\
e + b + f &= 180
\end{align}

In solving the first and second together we get $d=2x$ and in solving the third and fourth we get $2y=e$ as reqired.

For the second part of (a): The above result means that if we have the points $A$ and $B$ (and $O$ the center) we can make a triangle $AOB$ with an angle $\angle {AOB}$. Then for any point on the arc, call it $P$, we will have $\angle APB= \angle AOB$. Thus, the angle is indipendent of the choice of $P$.

**(b)**
Consider the following diagram
[image]

Where the labled angles come as a results of (a) (setting $M$ to $P$ and setting $N$ to $P$). Note that $MC|CK$ and $LC | CN$ and $\angle MCL = \angle NCK$ which implies that the triangles are similar and thereby $ML | NK$. Hence, the triangles $SNK$ and $SML$ are similar and thereby $$\frac{KS}{NS} = \frac{SM}{SL},$$
as required.

**(c)** Note that the greatest distance $x$ will be when his eye sight is tangent to the circle. Therefore, we use the [] text bellow (b) in the question to get that
$$\frac{h}{x}=\frac{x}{2+r}$$
$$ \therefore x= \sqrt{h(h+2r)}$$